# Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 412 Precondition Failed while removing bucket IAM Member

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-account, google-iam

In order to remove identities from a google cloud bucket, I use the example provided at the GCP examples repo: [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/snippets/BucketIamSnippets.java).  I am wondering if there is something I am missing, I have the correct root credentials to the cloud account, as well as the project ownership credentials.

**Here is the original policy:**

```
Policy{
bindings={roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner=[projectOwner:myaccount], 
roles/storage.objectAdmin=[serviceAccount:company-kiehn- 
log@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:company-hammes- 
file@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:company-howe- 
log@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:company-doyle- 
log@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:customer-6a53ee71-95eb- 
49b2-8a@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:company-kiehn- 
file@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:company-howe- 
file@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:company-satterfield- 
log@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:customer-0c1e8536-8bf5- 
46f4-8e@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com, serviceAccount:company-deckow- 
log@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com], 
roles/storage.legacyBucketReader=[projectViewer:myaccount], 
roles/storage.objectViewer=[serviceAccount:company-block- 
log@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com]},
etag=CGg=,
version=0}
```

**Here is my code snippet:**

**Read bucket policy and extract unwanted identities**

```
Set<Identity> wrongIdentities = new HashSet<Identity>();
Role roler = null;    
Policy p = Cache.GCSStorage.getIamPolicy("bucketxyz");
Map<Role, Set<Identity>> policyBindings = p.getBindings();
        for (Map.Entry<Role, Set<Identity>> entry : policyBindings.entrySet()) {
Set<Identity> setidentities = entry.getValue();
                for (Identity set : setidentities) {
                    if (!(entry.getKey().getValue()
                            .equals("serviceAccount:attss@myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com"))) {

                        wrongIdentities.add(set);
                    }
 }
for (Identity identity : wrongIdentities) {

            System.out.println("identity: " + identity);
            System.out.println(removeBucketIamMember("bucektxyz",
                    roler, identity, p));
        }
}
```

**Remove Unwanted Identities from policy**

```
public static Policy removeBucketIamMember(String bucketName, Role role, 
Identity identity, Policy policy) {
Policy updatedPolicy = Cache.GCSStorage.setIamPolicy(bucketName,
policy.toBuilder().removeIdentity(role, identity).build());
return updatedPolicy;
```

However, I am seeing the error:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 412 
Precondition Failed
{
   "code" : 412,
   "errors" : [ {
   "domain" : "global",
   "location" : "If-Match",
   "locationType" : "header",
   "message" : "Precondition Failed",
   "reason" : "conditionNotMet"
 } ],
   "message" : "Precondition Failed"
 }

at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.setIamPolicy(HttpStorageRpc.java:886)
... 9 more
```

Comment: Show the `policy` that you are using. You need to read the policy first, then modify it, before applying the new policy.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated the question. I have a method that reads the original policy and tries to filter out the unwanted identities before attempting to remove them.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are not using the updated policy each time you remove an identity. If you look at the policy there is a tag at the end: `etag=CGg=`. This changes each time the policy changes. You must read the policy before updating. I think that this is the `If-Match` failure. In your function, `removeBucketIamMember` do not pass the policy. Instead, read the policy, modify, write inside the function. Repeat as required.

Comment: @JohnHanley can you post your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When modifying the Cloud Storage bucket or object IAM policy, it is important to first read the policy. As part of the policy content is a tag. The updated policy must include the same tag. The tag looks like: `etag=CGg=`.

In this question the policy update was failing with HTTP error 412 Precondition Failed. This message is caused by the policy tag being incorrect. Since a policy update replaces an existing policy, this tag helps prevent two updates from overwriting each other.

Comment: the error has stopped therefore I have accepted your answer. However, the policy never gets updated.

Comment: see updated question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798852/deletion-of-users-identities-from-google-iam-policy-does-not-work