# Deletion of users (identities) from Google bucket IAM Policy does not work

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-iam

In order to remove identities from a google cloud bucket, I use the example provided at the GCP examples repo: [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/snippets/BucketIamSnippets.java).  I am wondering if there is something I am missing, I have the correct root credentials to the cloud account, as well as the project ownership credentials. Basically, the removal operations do not owrk both from `Java` code and using the `gsutil` function from `gcp` web console.

**Here is the original policy:**

```
Policy{  
bindings=   {  
  roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner=      [  
     projectOwner:csbauditor
  ],
  roles/storage.objectAdmin=      [  
     serviceAccount:company-kiehn-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-kiehn-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-howe-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-satterfield-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:customer-0c1e8536-8bf5-46f4-8e@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-fahey-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-hammes-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-howe-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-sipes-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-doyle-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:customer-6a53ee71-95eb-49b2-8a@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-bergnaum-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  ],
  roles/storage.legacyBucketReader=      [  
     projectViewer:csbauditor
  ],
  roles/storage.objectViewer=      [  
   serviceAccount:company-block-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  ]
 },
   etag=CLgE,
      version=0
 }
```

**Here is the second policy version, before writing to IAM:**

```
 Policy{  
 bindings=   {  
    roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner=      [  
      projectOwner:csbauditor
  ],
  roles/storage.objectAdmin=      [  
     serviceAccount:company-kiehn-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-kiehn-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-howe-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-satterfield-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:customer-0c1e8536-8bf5-46f4-8e@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-fahey-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-hammes-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-howe-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-sipes-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-doyle-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:customer-6a53ee71-95eb-49b2-8a@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
     serviceAccount:company-bergnaum-file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  ],
  roles/storage.legacyBucketReader=      [  
     projectViewer:csbauditor
  ],
  roles/storage.objectViewer=      [  
     serviceAccount:company-block-log@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  ]
},
etag=CLgE,
version=0
}
```

**Here is my code snippet:**

**Read bucket policy and extract unwanted identities**

```
Set<Identity> wrongIdentities = new HashSet<Identity>();
Role roler = null;    
Policy p = Cache.GCSStorage.getIamPolicy("bucketxyz");
Map<Role, Set<Identity>> policyBindings = p.getBindings();
    for (Map.Entry<Role, Set<Identity>> entry : policyBindings.entrySet()) {
Set<Identity> setidentities = entry.getValue();
    roler = entry.getKey();

        if (roler.getValue().equals("roles/storage.objectAdmin")) {
           setidentities = entry.getValue();
            if ((set.equals("serviceAccount:attacker@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com"))) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    wrongIdentities.add(set);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
  removeBucketIamMember("bucektxyz", roler, identity));
    }
 }
```

**Remove Unwanted Identities from policy**

```
public static Policy removeBucketIamMember(String bucketName, Role role, 
Identity identity) {
Storage storage = GoogleStorage.initStorage();
Policy policy = storage.getIamPolicy(bucketName);
System.out.println("policyt "+ policy);
Policy updatedPolicy = policy.toBuilder().removeIdentity(role, 
Identity.serviceAccount(identity.getValue())).build();
System.out.println("updatedPolicy "+ policy);
storage.setIamPolicy(bucketName,updatedPolicy);
if (updatedPolicy.getBindings().get(role) == null|| 
!updatedPolicy.getBindings().get(role).contains(identity)) { 
System.out.printf("Removed %s with role %s from %s\n", identity, role, 
bucketName);
} 
return updatedPolicy;
}
```

**Update 01**
I tried also using `gsutil` from within the web console, still does not work.

```
myaccount@cloudshell:~ (csbauditor)$ gsutil iam ch -d user:company-sipes- 
file@csbauditor.iam.gserviceaccount.com  gs://company-block-log-fce65e82-a0cd- 
4f71-8693-381100d93c18

No changes made to gs://company-block-log-fce65e82-a0cd-4f71-8693-381100d93c18/
```

**Update 02** As advised by @JohnHanley, `gsutil` worked after I replaced `user` with `serviceAccount`. However, the java code is not yet working.

Comment: Show both the policy as read and then again before you write it back formatted so I can easily read it. Put the JSON thru a formatting tool.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated the question, showing the very first version of the policy and immediate next.  Due to space reasons only these two are included, however there are no changes all through except for the `eTag` that constantly changes.

Comment: I wanted to see the policy after you change it but before you write it back to IAM. It looks like you are showing the policy after reading it in both examples.

Comment: @JohnHanley you are correct, I was earlier showing the policy after writing to IAM. I have updated it to show as you requested.

Comment: For your `gsutil` command change `user:` to `serviceAccount:` I am still looking at the rest of the question.

Comment: Where is `roler` being initialized at? Currently, your code shows it a null, which means the IAM delete code will do nothing.

Comment: Wow, i skipped showing that `roler` is initialized at `roler = entry.getKey();`. Updated the code right now, somehow skipped it before.

Comment: Like John said, change "user" for "serviceAccount" on the gsutil command, according to the type of member you are removing. Have in mind that if the member is not found (the change actually causes no change) you will get that message "No changes made" is not an error but the alert that your command didn't cause anything to change.  Also, your Java code is missing the closing ")"  after "Identity identity" on removeBucketIamMember ( second line ) Which error does your Java code gives you?.

Comment: @Mayeru thanks, gsutil now works after follwing JohnHanley's  advise. However, the java code still does nothing, there is also no error.

Comment: Did you fix the missing parenthesis ? is not giving any message either? (not even the print lines? )

Comment: @Mayeru The missing parenthesis is a typo, it not missing in the actual code. So, far there are no error messages. The print lines are printed as expected, nothing indicates there was an error, or if the policies are updated or not. It is really strange!

Comment: @JohnHanley do you have further recommendations on solving the problem?

Comment: @SyCode - I don't see a problem with the Java code. I would have to reproduce your problem by building the code.

Comment: I see. To seek further insights, I have opened an issue the google cloud java api GitHub repository (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/5581). It could be a bug.

Comment: I have tried out the snippets and they work well, I was able to list, add and remove a policy (identity/role), so I'm suspecting the issue is on your code, the fact that it doesn't even print you "policyt ..." tells me that it never entered on the remove function.  "identity" is not declared and there's a double "))" that i'm not sure where it opens, same with the if that opens "((" and closes ")))". Can you update the scripts with the actual code you are using so I rule out any typos?

Comment: @Mayeru that sound really promising to me. Can you take a look at the code at this gist (https://gist.github.com/SyCode7/2842c4f2fa38295c49b8aefd8f664100#file-gcsbucketpolicychecker).?

Comment: I think I have found the root to your issue, I have post it as an Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue in your code. Although I cannot be completely sure that this was the only issue since I wasn't able to compile your code, I had to change several classes too.

After I was able to compile and run the code I noticed that even if the "remove" function was executed nothing really happened, after making a few prints I noticed that it was trying to remove the services accounts using the wrong "role", since you were changing the "role" value on the "for" loop, and if the "set" wasn't equal to "attacker-service-account" then the loop made another iteration and changed the "role" value.

Here's the code of my class (a modification of the example snippet):

```
package com.google.cloud.examples.storage.snippets;

import com.google.cloud.Identity;
import com.google.cloud.Policy;
import com.google.cloud.Role;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageRoles;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/** This class contains Bucket-level IAM snippets for the {@link Storage} interface. */
public class BucketIamSnippets {

  /** Example of listing the Bucket-Level IAM Roles and Members */
  public Policy listBucketIamMembers(String bucketName) {
    // [START view_bucket_iam_members]
    // Initialize a Cloud Storage client
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // Get IAM Policy for a bucket
    Policy policy = storage.getIamPolicy(bucketName);

    // Print Roles and its identities
    Map<Role, Set<Identity>> policyBindings = policy.getBindings();
    for (Map.Entry<Role, Set<Identity>> entry : policyBindings.entrySet()) {
      System.out.printf("Role: %s Identities: %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    // [END view_bucket_iam_members]
    return policy;
  }

  /** Example of adding a member to the Bucket-level IAM */
  public Policy addBucketIamMember(String bucketName, Role role, Identity identity) {
    // [START add_bucket_iam_member]
    // Initialize a Cloud Storage client
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // Get IAM Policy for a bucket
    Policy policy = storage.getIamPolicy(bucketName);

    // Add identity to Bucket-level IAM role
    Policy updatedPolicy =
        storage.setIamPolicy(bucketName, policy.toBuilder().addIdentity(role, identity).build());

    if (updatedPolicy.getBindings().get(role).contains(identity)) {
      System.out.printf("Added %s with role %s to %s\n", identity, role, bucketName);
    }
    // [END add_bucket_iam_member]
    return updatedPolicy;
  }


  public static void removeUserFromBucketUsingEmail(String bucketName, Role role, String email)  {

        Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService(); 
        Policy policy = storage.getIamPolicy(bucketName);
        Identity identity = Identity.serviceAccount(email);
        String eTag = policy.getEtag();
        System.out.println("etag: " + eTag);

        Policy updatedPolicy = storage.setIamPolicy(bucketName, policy.toBuilder().removeIdentity(role, identity).build());

    if (updatedPolicy.getBindings().get(role) == null
        || !updatedPolicy.getBindings().get(role).contains(identity)) {
      System.out.printf("Removed %s with role %s from %s\n", identity, role, bucketName);
    }


    }


public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    try
    {

    String bucketName = "my-bucket-name";

    BucketIamSnippets obj = new BucketIamSnippets ();
    Role role_admin = StorageRoles.objectAdmin();

    String acc_1 = "test1@my.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    String acc_2 = "test2@my.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    Identity identity_1 = Identity.serviceAccount(acc_1);
    Identity identity_2 = Identity.serviceAccount(acc_2);

     System.out.println(obj.addBucketIamMember (bucketName, role_admin, identity_1 ));
     System.out.println(obj.addBucketIamMember (bucketName, role_admin, identity_2 ));


      Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        Policy policy = storage.getIamPolicy(bucketName);
        System.out.println(policy);

        //List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Set<Identity>> identities = new ArrayList<>();
        // Print Roles and its identities
        Set<Identity> wrongIdentities = new HashSet<Identity>();
        Role aux = null;

        Map<Role, Set<Identity>> policyBindings = policy.getBindings();
        Set<Identity> setidentities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Role, Set<Identity>> entry : policyBindings.entrySet()) {
            aux = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println("role plain " + aux);
            System.out.println("role other  " + aux.getValue());

            if (aux.getValue().equals("roles/storage.objectAdmin")) {
                System.out.println("role :" + aux.getValue());
                System.out.println("Identities getV :" + entry.getValue());
                System.out.println("Identities getK :" + entry.getKey());

                setidentities = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println("setidentities  :" + setidentities);
                System.out.println("setidentities size :" + setidentities.size());
                for (Identity set : setidentities) {
                    if ((set.equals("serviceAccount: test2@my.iam.gserviceaccount.com"))) {
                        System.out.println("strong one : " + set);
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        wrongIdentities.add(set);
                        System.out.println("strong one : " + set);

                    }

                    System.out.println("wrongIdentities.size() : " + wrongIdentities.size());

                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("ww " + wrongIdentities);
        System.out.println("policyEtag " + policy.getEtag());
        //GCSFunctions function = new GCSFunctions(); 

        for (Identity identity : wrongIdentities) {
            BucketIamSnippets.removeUserFromBucketUsingEmail(bucketName, role_admin, identity.getValue());
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}

}
```

Notes:

1. I add two test services accounts and then I run your code (with a little modifications).
2. I have initialized the "role" as objectAdmin directly, and that's what i pass to the removing function.
3. Modify the code to comply with your actual use case.
4. I have compiled this with the same dependencies used on the [example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-examples)

Comment: thank you very much, you got it accurately. You are a `genius`!  The code works well now. The `roles` were not set appropriately, and you also showed how to initialize the role so that they remain constant  e.g. `roles/storage.objectAdmin`.

Comment: Glad to know it was helpful to you : )